# Memory-Mapping Slows Down Over Time, Alternatives?

Tags: python, performance, unix, numpy, memory-mapped-files

I have around 700 matrices stored on disk, each with around 70k rows and 300 columns.

I have to load *parts* of these matrices relatively quickly, around 1k rows per matrix, into another matrix I have in memory. The fastest way I found to do this is using memory maps, where initially I am able to load the 1k rows in around 0.02 seconds. However, performance is not consistent at all and sometimes, loading takes up to 1 second per matrix!

My code looks like this roughly:

```
target = np.zeros((7000, 300))
target.fill(-1)  # allocate memory

for path in os.listdir(folder_with_memmaps):
    X = np.memmap(path, dtype=_DTYPE_MEMMAPS, mode='r', shape=(70000, 300))
    indices_in_target = ... # some magic
    indices_in_X = ... # some magic
    target[indices_in_target, :] = X[indices_in_X, :]
```

With line by line timing I determined that it is definitely the last line that slows down over time.

---

**Upadte**: Plotting the load times gives different results. One time it looked like this, i.e. the degrade was not gradual but instead jumped after precisely 400 files. Could this be some OS limit?

[image: Plot1]

But another time it looked completely different:

[image: Plot2]

After a few more test runs, it seems that second plot is rather typical of the performance development.

---

Also, I tried to `del X` after the loop, without any impact. Neither did accessing the underlying Python `mmap` via `X._mmap.close()` work.

---

Any ideas as to why there is inconsistent performance? Are there any faster alternatives to store & retrieve these matrices?

Comment: It looks like the underlying `mmap` file isn't being closed when you move on to the next file.  This is a wild guess, but I'd try adding a `del X` at the end of the loop.  The code for `np.memmap` is readable Python, but that for `mmap.mmap` is not.

Comment: What is the range of the indices and are they sorted? I.e. it matters if `indices_in_X` is `np.arange(1000)` or `np.random.shuffe(np.arange(0, 70000, 70))`. Also, try to make the timings independent from OS file caching effects: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87908

Comment: @morningsun Thanks for the reply. I tried sorting the `indices_in_X` as well as `indices_in_target` and I think it improves the baseline slightly, but the seemingly random degration patches are still there. Also unfortunately I am working on a shared server and don't have any sudo privileges, so I cannot purge any caches.

Comment: Since this is a shared server, how likely is it that other users are doing something that causes the inconsistent performance?  If that is likely, is there a time when you can test your code without anyone else on the server?

Comment: Do those load times include program startup, or are they taken inside your code? How are you controlling the number of files tested?

Comment: Do you know how much free memory is available on the server? The effects of thrashing could feasibly cause significant and intermittent performance penalties.

Comment: @Aenimated1 What do you mean with trashing?

Comment: @Useless They are inside the code. The number of files is always the same…?

Comment: @MattJordan These seems to be what is going on, see Ulrich's answer.

Comment: I was referring to [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)), in which there isn't adequate physical memory to accommodate all the processes, so there is a large number of page faults resulting in considerable resources being spent on overhead page swapping operations.  If this is happening on your server, the other "master" that the HDD is serving could simply be the OS' virtual memory manager.

Comment: It's totally normal for disk operations to vary by a factor of 10 or more in speed. Head seeks take on the order of 3 milliseconds each, and then there's a wait of average roughly 2ms more for data to reach the head.  5ms is enough to read about 20 megabytes of data. My guess is you're seeing an artifact of your OS scheduler. When your process starts running it gets long chunks of time so dominates the disk. OSs do that so interactive apps are responsive. After that it's pre-empted more often. Would be interesting to try bumping up process priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HDDs are poor at "serving more than one master" -- the slowdown can be much larger than one might expect.  To demonstrate, I used this code to read the backup files (about 50 MB each) on the HDD of my Ubuntu 12.04 machine:

```
import os, random, time

bdir = '/hdd/backup/'
fns = os.listdir(bdir)

while True:
  fn = random.choice(fns)
  if not fn.startswith("duplicity-full."):
    continue
  ts = time.time()
  with open(bdir+fn, 'rb') as f:
    c = f.read()
  print "MB/s: %.1f" %(len(c)/(1000000*(time.time()-ts)))
```

Running one of these "processes" gives me decent read performance:

```
MB/s: 148.6
MB/s: 169.1
MB/s: 184.1
MB/s: 188.1
MB/s: 185.3
MB/s: 146.2
```

Adding a second such process in parallel slows things down by more than an order of magnitude:

```
MB/s: 14.3
MB/s: 11.6
MB/s: 12.7
MB/s: 8.7
MB/s: 8.2
MB/s: 15.9
```

My guess is this (i.e., other HDD use) is the reason for your inconsistent performance.  My hunch is an SSD would do significantly better.  For my machine, for large files on the SSD the slowdown due to a parallel reader process was only twofold, from about 440 MB/s to about 220 MB/s.  (See my comment.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I requested access to a server with SSDs, will see how it goes

Comment: I just did a quick test on my SSD with some large files.  One process: about 440 MB/s; with second process in parallel: about 220 MB/s.  So the SSD is much better than the HDD at "serving two masters" in this case.

Comment: Assuming float (4 bytes) is sufficient, without compression the 700 matrices take about 59 GB, making an "all main memory" solution possible on a beefy server.  And Gary's suggestion (bcolz) or other compression may help for either a disk or main memory solution.

Comment: Hi again. So as you excepted, the SSDs make things much faster and more consistent! So I am willing to believe that "serving >1 masters" was the problem. Re the "all main memory" solution: I actually have 700 gigs available now (!) but I have to transform the matrices in a second step to make them much higher dimensional, so I cannot load all the matrices _and_ keep the transformed stuff in memory at once, even with that ridiculous amount of memory.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using [bcolz](http://bcolz.blosc.org/en/latest/intro.html) .  It compresses numerical data on disk and in memory to speed things up.  You may have to transpose the matrices in order to get a sparse read since bcolz stores things by column rather than row.

Comment: Thanks! Sound promising. Using SSDs I get fairly reasonable performance, I will have to see with my supervisors if implementing `bcolz` is worth the effort now.